# find first contains match from array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm trying to write a cloud function. I have a const array of keywords, such as:

```
const berriesKeywords = [
    "berries",
    "berry",
    "cherries",
    "grapes",
    "kumquats",
    "currant"
]
```

The cloud function accepts a list of ingredients `data.ingredients` that, e.g., might contain:

```
[
    "tomatoes",
    "romain lettuce",
    "concord grapes",
    "tempeh"
    "kumquats",
    "currant"
]
```

I want to traverse each `berriesKeywords` until I find a contains match in `data.ingredients`. In the example above, we should stop at `grapes`, because of `concord grapes`. So basically I only care if there was one match. What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach

- Using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on `berriesKeywords` to find the first match
- Using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find a match for a single value of `berriesKeywords` among `ingredients`
- Using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to have a partial string match between a single value of `berriesKeywords` and a single value of `ingredients`

```js
const berriesKeywords = [
    "berries",
    "berry",
    "cherries",
    "grapes",
    "kumquats",
    "currant"
]

const ingredients = [
    "tomatoes",
    "romain lettuce",
    "concord grapes",
    "tempeh",
    "kumquats",
    "currant"
]

const result = berriesKeywords.find(berriesKeyword => ingredients.some(ingredient => ingredient.includes(berriesKeyword)))

console.log(result)
```

Here is [the playground](https://jsfiddle.net/ev1q2fu8/) if you cannot run it here

By the way, these functions are from Javascript but have no differences in Typescript, so you can use them without any problems.